# D3.js enable/disable dragging programmatically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As far as I understand, it should be possible to programmatically enable/disable the drag behavior and always maintain the zoom behavior in the d3.js.

However I do no get that to work correctly.

I have enabled zoom by the following code.
This code alone also enables dragging.

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .on('zoom', zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);
```

My hopes are to be able to control just the dragging/panning operation by using the `dragging`-API, and if I use the following code the drag listener will indeed not work, but the zoom will:

```
const drag = d3.drag()
    .on('start', d3.disableDrag)

svg.call(drag);
```

That said I figured I would be able to enable/disable the dragging/panning as I wish under certain circumstances. For example, if the zoom is at it's original state (`scale 1`), then dragging should disable. If the scale state is `> 1`, then panning should enable.

This is my complete code

```
const dragEnabled = false;
const drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", d3.disableDrag)

svg.call(drag);

const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);    

function disableDrag() {
    svg.call(drag.on("start", d3.disableDrag));
}

function enableDrag() {
    svg.call(drag.on("start", d3.enableDrag));
    dragEnabled = true;
}

function zoomed(event) {
    const { transform } = event;
    const { k: scale } = transform;

    group.attr("transform", transform);
    group.attr("stroke-width", 1 / scale);

    switch(true) {
        case scale <= 1:
            disableDrag();
            break;

        default:
            if(!dragEnabled) enableDrag();
    }
}
```

The result when I run this code is

- Dragging/panning is not enabled when I first load my project [Good]
- Dragging/panning does enable when I zoom [Good]
- When I zoom out to the original scale state (1), then I am still able to drag/pan [Bad!]

Do anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

**Simple demo**

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const group = d3.select('g#content');
let dragEnabled = false;

const drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", d3.disableDrag)

svg.call(drag);

const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);    

function disableDrag() {
    svg.call(drag.on("start", null));
}

function enableDrag() {
    svg.call(drag.on("start", null));
    dragEnabled = true;
}

function zoomed(event) {
    const { transform } = event;
    const { k: scale } = transform;

    group.attr("transform", transform);
    group.attr("stroke-width", 1 / scale);

    switch(true) {
        case scale <= 1:
            disableDrag();
            break;

        default:
            if(!dragEnabled) enableDrag();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg width="1200" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1200 500">
      <g id="content">
         <path d="M10,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
         <path d="M70,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
         <path d="M130,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
         <path d="M190,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
      </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

External JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1vyw0tL6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing as mention is it's `d3.dragDisable` and not `d3.disableDrag`. However regardless that function requires a `window` object to work.

I've tried to go for the result I think you're trying to achieve while also answering the specific "why isn't this working" question.

I've done some stuff with dragging before, and I've never tried to do it this way. Had to try and remember how I've done it before. So the reason what you've got isn't working is because the `zoomed` event fires even when panning...

So to fix this, firstly we're going to strip it right back. You found `scaleExtent` but if you combine with [translateExtent](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_translateExtent) you can achieve what you're after a lot more simply.
The only thing that tripped me up, it seems you can't call both `d3.zoom()` and `d3.drag()` on the same element, so I've moved the drag down to the `<g>`.

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const group = d3.select('g#content');

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 15])
  .translateExtent([[0,0],[1200,500]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
  
svg.call(zoom);    
svg.call(d3.drag());

function zoomed(event) {
  const { transform } = event;
  const { k: scale } = transform;

  group.attr("transform", transform);
  group.attr("stroke-width", 1 / scale);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg width="1200" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1200 500">
      <g id="content">
         <path d="M10,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
         <path d="M70,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
         <path d="M130,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
         <path d="M190,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50 Z" />
      </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks fot your reply. Here is the documentation for `disableDrag()`: https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#dragDisable. I did try `null` too - same result. I have also verified that it does call my function. I'll try to setup an easy demo.

Comment: @entiendoNull so that function is `dragDisable`, the words are transposed. The other thing is it expects a `window` object, but you'll be passing the `svg` selection, so I'm not sure you're current approach is correct.

Comment: Uuh, that's embarrassing :') I tried it this way now `svg.call(drag.on("start", () => d3.dragDisable(window)));` but still had no luck. I'll put up an example to illustrate. But do you reckon this should be possible?

Comment: @entiendoNull sure it's possible :) Just need somewhere to play around to fix it for you.

Comment: I've updated my post with a very simple demo. There's also a fiddle if you prefer :)

Comment: @entiendoNull just in case you hadn't seen, I updated my answer for you :)

Comment: thank you very much for your effort! I hadn't seen your updated answer. I will try it out in practice. The only thing I notice that's weird is that I can seem to drag when I have the mouse over the paths (rectangles). Did you notice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235888/discussion-between-entiendonull-and-ian).